# Need to extract middle hex portion from the tcpdump output

Tags: linux, shell, awk, cut, tcpdump

Here is a tcpdump hex output of a captured packet.

Command used was ..

```
$ tcpdump -X -s0 protochain <portno> 

0x0000:  6000 0000 0080 3220 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0x0040:  0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0x0090:  6174 6500 0000 0329                      ........
```

these `...` could be anything they are respective ascii charaters corresponding to the specified hex characters. I need to extract the middle hex portion.

I need output in the following format. Please suggest me something on this.

```
6000 0000 0080 3220 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000
6174 6500 0000 0329
```

I tried this one but that seems incorrect ..

```
cut -d ":" -f2 tmp_packet.txt | awk -F " " '{printf "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s 
\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8}' > packet.txt
```

tried something with `cut -b` also but that is giving weird output.

If possible suggest something with awk `NR`and `NF`. I am new to awk so do not know much about them.

I tried this and get those `...` as output.

```
cut -d ":" -f2 tmp_packet.txt | awk -F " " '{printf "%s\n",$NF}' > packet.txt
```

**output :**

```
................
................
........
```

Is there any way using awk to print all the columns except the last one (that is to print everything except the above specified).

Comment: Simple way would be to just do hexdump of your raw pcap. `hexdump -x raw.pcap | awk '{$1="";print}'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cut by spaces: `cut -d " "  -f 3-10`

Comment: that won't work for third line because 7th field delimited by space would be those `....` in the output

Comment: @UditGupta: Have you tested that?

Comment: okkk.. that worked out but the reason why I did not tested is because this one does not worked out  `cut -d ":" -f2 tmp_packet.txt | awk -F " " '{printf "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s 
  \n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8}' > packet.txt`. so if possible please explain when cut and wak both are taking dlimiter as `space` then why their output differ

Comment: `cut` doesn't collapse spaces. Runs of spaces count as multiple fields. Note that this is much faster than `grep` because you don't need to do any complex matching at all.

Comment: Nice! Can someone please show some compassion with my fugly awk solution! ;)

Comment: @Jaypal: There's a time and a place for `awk`, and I'm sure you'll get your chance to shine before long! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can try using grep as:

```
egrep -o '([0-9]{4} ){1,8}'  input
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/wnflv)

Answer (score 0):

Your AWK Solution - `awk '{for(i=2;i<=9;i++) printf $i" ";printf "\n"}' file | sed 's/\.*//g'`

```
[jaypal~/Temp]$ cat file
0x0000:  6000 0000 0080 3220 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0x0040:  0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0x0090:  6174 6500 0000 0329                      ........

[jaypal~/Temp]$ awk '{for(i=2;i<=9;i++) printf $i" ";printf "\n"}' file | sed 's/\.*//g'
6000 0000 0080 3220 0000 0000 0000 0000 
0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 
6174 6500 0000 0329
```

Another way of printing via AWK -

```
[jaypal~/Temp]$ awk '{$1="";$10=""; print}' file | sed 's/\.*//g'
 6000 0000 0080 3220 0000 0000 0000 0000 
 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 
 6174 6500 0000 0329
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/.\{9\}\(.\{39\}\).*/\1/' file
```

or if you want to remove trailing spaces:

```
sed 's/.\{9\}\(.\{39\}\).*/\1/;s/\s*$//' file
```